# Refresh `vimgrep` list?

Tags: vimgrep

I use `vimgrep` with `:cnew` and `:cold` a lot.  I could be looking at a `vimgrep` list from several `vimgrep` commands ago.  Is there a way to refresh the `vimgrep` list without typing in the corresponding `vimgrep` command?  It might be quite far up in the command history, so it often takes more time to find it.  By refresh, I mean search through all the files that were searched in the original issuance of the `vimgrep` command.  Some may have been changed due to editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always do `<up>` on the command line with a prefix of `:vimgrep` to make searching history easier. You may also want to check out `q:` and the use `?`/`/` to search for the command to re-execute.

Assuming the quickfix title is set correctly, you can use following the command:

```
:execute get(getqflist({'title':1}), 'title')
```

This however I am not certain this will work with all `:grep`/`:make` commands. You also need a newer Vim version to get the Quckfix list title (Vim 8+ I think).

If you find yourself doing this often you may want to bind a mapping or command.

```
command! -nargs=0 -bar QFRefresh execute get(getqflist({'title':1}), 'title')
```

For more help see:

```
:h getqflist()
:h :execute
:h :get
:h q:
:h cmdwin
:h c_Up
```

Comment: Thanks, Peter.  I like your initial, simple suggestion best, since I'm up and running without a detour.  I am also in a much-controlled environment, and upgrading anything would entail unimaginable amounts of time.